Getting VS403247: Unable to access the package location while trying to migrate TFS 2022 on prem to Azure DevOps services using Migrator tool
We have TFS 2018 on Prem which I migrated to TFS2022 on Prem so that it can be migrated to DevOps services on cloud.
While trying to migrate using Migrator I am executing the following commands.
Migrator.exe Validate /collection:<collection URL> /tenantDomainName:<TenantDomainName> - Validates everything.

Migrator.exe prepare /collection:<collection URL> /tenantDomainName:<TenantDomainName> /Region:CUS - Creates import.json, identityMapLog.csv and other files.

Then I am detaching the collection database to migrate using Azure DevOps Server Administration Console.
In the next step I am creating the DacPac file using sqlpackage.exe
I logged into the storage account, and created new container where I want to upload the DacPac file.
I created a SAS key for newly created container and gave list and read permissions along with a validity of 6 months for the SAS key.
Updated import.json to include the name of the DacPac file,Location of DacPac file using sas url ,Target organization and import type = DryRun.
I uploaded the DacPac file , import.json and identitymaplog.csv to a container in a storage account.
Ran command
Migrator.exe import /importfile:<local path to import.json>\import.json

At that time I am getting:

Error VS403247: Unable to access the location 'https://.blob.core.windows.net/ error.

Any help resolving this issue will be highly appreciated. I have been struck with this error for weeks and don't know what to do.
I tried to use the SAS URL directly in the browser, at first I was getting
Signature did not match. String to sign used was rl error.
Then I added &comp=list&resttype=container to the sas url and it lists the contents of the folder in the browser.

Hi @AnkitThakkar, what's the latest state after creating a new storage account? Was the migration successful after importing to a storage account without any network settings?

To generate an SAS token for import, according to the doc,


Select only Read and List as permissions for your SAS token.
Set an expiry time no further than seven days into the future
Restrict access to Azure DevOps Services IPs only.
Place the SAS token in a secure location.


When I only select the default Read permission for my SAS token, I get the same error as you. Ensure you select both Read and List as permissions.

Copy the complete Blob SAS URL and paste it to Location in import.json.


Run Migrator import /importFile:{location of import specification file}, it works fine.


Hi Ziyang Liu-MSFT, Thank you for the reply. SAS token already has Read and List permissions. I created the list of IPs that needs access to storage account from the link you shared. I think that must be the missing part. I am going to have meeting with the Systems department who can grant access to those ips. I will update the ticket once  Azure DevOps services IPs are granted access to storage account. Thanks.

In my actual testing, my Allowed IP addresses had no values populated. Your main problem now is that you cannot access the storage account when importing.  In order to know whether it is related to the network settings of your storage account,  you can create a new storage account with default settings. Then use it to import and check if it works.

It gave me about 8 to 10 ips to add. While systems dept is looking at this, it is a great suggestion to try with a new storage account.
I will do that and see if that works
Thank you. Really appreciate your help.

It's my pleasure to help you. The new storage account shouldn't have any custom network settings, just keep as default.
